# Get the currentSrc of responsive image on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, safari, srcset

I am trying to define a placeholder for when I click an image with photoswipe plugin. I would like to define exactly the same version of my responsive image as the image displayed on my screen.

```
data-srcset="
http://url.com/img-240.jpg 240w, 
http://url.com/img-360.jpg 360w, 
http://url.com/img-480.jpg 480w, 
http://url.com/img-720.jpg 720w "
```

Above are the different versions of my image.

My challenge is to get the current image displayed. For this, I use the `currentSrc` property, which works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari.

```
var currentSrc = imgEl.currentSrc || imgEl.src;
```

I didn't find anything about a possible solution for Safari & `currentSrc`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `naturalWidth` property as a fallback for Safari.

Although the spec says that `naturalWidth` should give the DPR-corrected width, it appears that in WebKit it returns the image's intrinsic width without DPR-correction. So only use this as a fallback if `currentSrc` does not exist.

Note: some versions of Edge support only `x` descriptors and also lack support for `currentSrc`, but I don't know what it does for `naturalWidth`. Newer versions of Edge support `w` and `currentSrc`.

Comment: Adding some info: Edge 12 doesn't offer `currentSrc` but Edge 13 does.  Safari 9.1 supports `currentSrc` now but I don't know when that started.